# how to create a DDL from sqlserver 2008 using command line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ddl

I am trying to get the full DB DDL from a SQLServer 2008 using just a command line, is there a way to do this with BCP? or other SQLServer tool?

Comment: You mean the same as from SSMS `Script Database as...Create To...File`  command?

Comment: exactly I need a command line to get all DB with tables, functions, indexes and triggers, but no data just structure

Answer (score 0):

I created [SMOscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/smoscript-0-19/) which creates a script for all objects in a database, or one script file per object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use third party tools, you can do it with the SQL Compare command line by comparing a database with an empty database.

sqlcompare.exe /s1:yourserver /db1:yourdatabase /s2:yourserver /db2:ablankdatabasethat youcreateinadvance /scriptfile:myscriptfile.sql